What 70's/80's movie? A woman with letter 'A' in her dress is comdemned of witchcraft
What movie/tv series is this? A woman in 16th/17th (?) century is hiding her identity, because she either is thought to be a witch or is a witch, and there is a letter 'A' in the upper part of her dress. I think she also has a child (small daughter) with her. The witches are burnt at the stake if found.

@AndrewThompson You're not really supposed to adapt a question to its answer once found.

@NapoleonWilson My bad..

Sounds like The Scarlet Letter, and from the time period it's likely Wim Wenders' version from 1973:

In 17th-century Salem, Hester Prynne must wear a scarlet A because she is an adulteress, with a child out of wedlock. For seven years, she has refused to name the father. A vigorous older stranger arrives, recognized by Hester but unknown to others as her missing husband. He poses as Chillingworth, a doctor, watching Hester and searching out the identity of her lover. 

If that doesn't fit, there was also a miniseries in 1979 with Meg Foster and a much maligned 1995 film.

Yes, it is the miniseries I was looking, I remember the red dress and a decorative 'A'. Thanks!
